# group_by error within the user-defined-function

Tags: r, dataframe, user-defined-functions

```
df_devw %>% 
    group_by(year, wage_tile) %>% 
    summarize(mean_engi = mean(d_engi)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = mean_engi)enter code here

tbl <- function(x){
    df_devw %>%
    group_by(year, wage_tile) %>%
    summarize(mean_value = mean(x)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = mean_value)
    }
tbl(df_devw$d_engi)
```

Hello, I'm struggling with the user-defined-function in R.

How comes the two codes above does not print the same result?
The second code using user-defined-function prints the result without using group_by.
It prints the mean value of whole data set (not by 'year' and 'wage_tile')

Thank you.

Comment: Read this <https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html>

Answer (score 2):

The function can be modified to pass the object name and the column name (unquoted) and then use curly-curly (`{{}}`) operator to return the value of the column

```
f1 <- function(dat, x){
    dat %>%
    group_by(year, wage_tile) %>%
    summarize(mean_value = mean({{x}})) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = mean_value)
    }
```

-testing

```
f1(df_devw, d_engi)
```